# stream_with_context and stream_template raising a RuntimeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am working from the following documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/
The following is a good portion of the traceback

```
  File "(my template)", line 85, in block "scripts"
    {{ super() }}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 27, in block "scripts"
    <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('jquery.js', cdn='jquery')}}"></script>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/__init__.py", line 93, in bootstrap_find_resource
    config = current_app.config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
```

The following is my code:

```
@app.route('/render', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def render():
  form = MyForm(request.form)
  if request.method == 'POST'
    def generate():
      for i,v in enumerate(my_data):
        yield (i,v)
    return Response(stream_template('results.html'), form=form, results=stream_with_context(generate))
  else:
    return render_template('advanced.html')

def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv
```

while I did notice that the documentation explicitly said `Without the stream_with_context() function you would get a RuntimeError at that point.`, I don't see why this is causing a runtime error despite already having a stream_with_context included

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely familiar with what you're doing in the `stream_template` method, but based on the example, you need to use `stream_with_context` on the first argument to `Response`, not around a template parameter.

If you need to stream based on the template, then maybe the template needs to be a part of the generate function.